# Etiquetas demasiado específicas

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

No sé cómo se crean las etiquetas, pero no sé si deberían existir etiquetas demasiado específicas. Por ejemplo, hace 3 horas se creó la etiqueta [combobox](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/combobox) en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11596/error-bot%C3%B3n-modificar-combobox), aunque está con la etiqueta [java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java). Creo que mejor sería usar una etiqueta como swing si es algo en desktop, o jsf si es algo web, o en última instancia restringir la creación de etiquetas demasiado específicas.

Answer (score 2):

Las etiquetas las puede crear [cualquier usuario con 150 o más de reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) cuando crea o edita una pregunta y escribe un texto en la sección de etiquetas. Si la etiqueta no existe, esta será creada automáticamente.

Las etiquetas sirven para categorizar las preguntas y facilita encontrarlas para proveer respuestas o participar con comentarios. Yo concuerdo con lo que indica @JuanPinzón de que no deberían crearse etiquetas muy específicas y con significado y uso tan amplio como [combobox](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/combobox). Pueden alegar que [existe una etiqueta combobox en la comunidad de inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/combobox/info), que tiene su información de wiki y demás información propia de una etiqueta. Pero hay que recordar que **esta no es la comunidad de idioma inglés, es la comunidad de habla hispana**, por ende tenemos **nuestras propias reglas**. Por ende, depende de nosotros decidir si debemos aceptar esta regla como comunidad. Mi voto es a favor.

Cabe resaltar que la creación y nombre de etiquetas es un tema asociado al criterio personal. Por ello, les pido a los usuarios con este privilegio **por favor** considerar si debe crearse una etiqueta para algo tan particular o con tan múltiple y diverso uso y significado en diferentes tecnologías.

Aquí dejo algunas ideas sobre cuándo deberíamos crear una etiqueta:

- Lenguaje de programación. Aunque sea recóndito y algo oscuro, pero solo si la pregunta es pertinente. Por ejemplo: [c#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), etc. Un ejemplo de un lenguaje con menos uso (al menos en este sitio) sería [r](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) (pero veo que está ganando su popularidad :) ). Un ejemplo de un lenguaje recóndito (que no he visto hasta ahora y no me lo esperaría) sería [brainfuck](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brainfuck).
- Sistemas operativos y Tecnología. Similar a lenguaje de programación. Ejemplos: [windows](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows), [android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), [ios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios), [linux](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux), [as400](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/as400).
- Frameworks: [django](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django), [swing](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing), [entity-framework](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework), [hibernate](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hibernate).
- Concepto de programación: [tag:método](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/m%C3%A9todo/info), [paso-por-valor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paso-por-valor), [paso-por-valor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paso-por-valor), [excepciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excepciones)

En caso de encontrar una pregunta con una etiqueta *extraña*, recomiendo que se realice una pregunta aquí en meta para evaluarla en la comunidad. Asimismo, se recomienda que dicha pregunta se comunique en la [sala de chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) para que los usuarios que participamos allí podamos revisar la pregunta y aportar nuestras ideas al respecto.

Comment: Son muy buenas alternativas, lo que me gustaría saber es: **¿Existe alguna manera de moderar las etiquetas, o se puede proponer una funcionalidad parecida?**

Comment: @JuanPinzón acabo de editar la pregunta para responder lo que indicas.

Comment: Entendido, gracias!

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Excelente respuesta, adoptemos estas tus sugerencias desde hoy en adelante.